# can't shutdown tomcat service on Mac

Tags: macos, tomcat

I installed the Apache Tomcat/7.0.65 on my Mac, then, run the startup.sh. It works great fine and the service is available immediately. But when I run the shutdown.sh to stop the service. It seems that the shell scripts can not aware of the tomcat running. Would someone please help me with this problem?

[image]

Comment: See the logs after startup (`~/apache-tomcat-7.0.65/logs/catalina.out`) whether there are no errors.

Comment: Can you check `netstat` to see if Tomcat is actually listening on port 8005?

Comment: Please check **port** attribute value of **Server** element in `~/apache-tomcat-7.0.65/conf/server.xml`. `shutdown.sh` does not work if the value is -1.

Comment: @JozefChocholacek   I restart my computer, then it works fine. ：）

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar problem. In my case, although running `<Tomcat Root>/bin>./shutdown.sh` was technically working (the tomcat process was being killed), the tomcat service was restarting automatically (after a few seconds).

If you run `<Tomcat Root>/bin/catalina.sh stop` or `<Tomcat Root>/bin/shutdown.sh` and you see that after a few seconds tomcat restarts => that basically means that you are not able to shutdown tomcat for good. Thus, if you want to make sure that tomcat does not restart automatically, run `brew services stop tomcat`.

OBS: If you want to find what is your `<Tomcat Root>` run `brew ls tomcat`